# Hexagon arrangements

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many unique ways (i.e. no reflection or rotation) can 5 identical hexagons be arranged on a plane.  Hexagons must be placed side by side, not corner to corner.

I have drawn the solutions for arranging 3 hexagons, 4 hexagons, and 5 hexagons, but am trying to derive a formula for n hexagons...with no success!)

thanks

Comment: Please add the context of this problem, and ideally link to pictures of your solutions for 3 and 4 hexagons (5 was a typo, right?). (See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/26369))The answers I'd give for this if it's a programming exercise are very different than the answers I'd give if you were a research mathematician and wanted this to compare for something else, etc.

Comment: I believe this is what you are asking for: [OEIS: A000228](http://oeis.org/A000228)

Comment: hi, I cant seem to add a picture!

Comment: hi, I cant seem to add a picture!  so, if you had 3 identical hexagonal tiles on a desk, how many ways could they be arranged? (ensuring at least one side of each tile touches at least one side of another tile) The answer to this is 3 ways: either all 3 in a row, 2 in a row and the third offset, or all 3 together in a triangular arrangement. Any other arrangement would be a reflection or rotation of one of these.  If you were to have four hexagons then there are 7 arrangements.  If you had 5 tiles, then how many would there be?  Is there a rule to calculate how many arrangements for n tiles?

Comment: my profile picture is my solution to the 5 tile problem!  hope this helps